# Using the long form of a section title in the TOC

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to use a full section title for:

- the section title itself (of course)
- the table of contents
- the running heads

But, I would like a short name to be used with `\nameref{}`, because otherwise the reference is too long to work into the surrounding text effectively. (The reader finding the section is not a problem because the sections are in alphabetical order and the short version will be the beginning of the section title.) `nameref` uses the short title if one is provided, but then the short title ends up in the table of contents as well, which I don't want. Is there a way to get the table of contents to use the long titles, leaving the short title for `nameref`? Alternatively, if there's a way to specify a different title than the section title itself for nameref to use, that would work as well.

I found many other questions and tips about using a short version in page headers and a long version in the table of contents, but nothing that involved `\nameref{}`.

The page header is not a problem as I'm using `memoir` and can easily define the page header separately (as the same as the full title, in this case).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\headnameref

% headers
\copypagestyle{maudcyclo}{plain}
\createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{\sectionname}{}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{maudcyclo}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\scshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{maudcyclo}{}{\scshape\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}

\makeevenhead{plain}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}

% don't number chapters and below
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\pagestyle{maudcyclo} % use header style

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section[Section One][S1]{Section One}
\label{sec1}
Here is some text for section one.
\clearpage

\section[Section Two][S2]{Section Two}
Here I will reference \nameref{sec1}.

\end{document}
```

The above MWE works properly except for the fact that it places `S1` and `S2` in the header, whereas I want `Section One` and `Section Two` there.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: i'm not a `memoir` user, but a possible approach can be posited from the manual.  two optional arguments are provided for the sectioning commands: `[`*toc name*`][`*head name*`]{`*full name*`}`, and `\nameref` can be set to use `\headnameref` (sec.16.2, p.303).  so you could repeat the full name for the toc name, and insert your short name as the head name.

Comment: @Barbara: That works, except it uses the short name in the header since I've now used the header argument that I was intending to make the same as the main title. (I did look in the manual but didn't see that part.) I would be willing to go with this if I have to, but I would rather get it working right. If there is a way to redefine \leftmark or \rightmark to use the full title or TOC title instead of the header title (which seems like an odd thing to do), that would fix it.

Comment: @Sean: Done. I had thought it wouldn't be useful for this problem, but I read the page you linked and that makes sense.

Comment: since the author of `memoir` observed that it was necessary to define `\nameref` within the class (on account of conflicts with the "usual" packages), it seems that your situation is a reasonable candidate for a feature/option request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two applications of `\patchcmd` (from the `etoolbox` package) are sufficent:

```
\patchcmd{\H@old@sectm@m}
  {\csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}}
  {\csname #1mark\endcsname{#9}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\H@old@sectm@m}
  {\fi #7}
  {\fi #9}
  {}{}
```

Running heads will be the full section title while `\nameref` maintains its originary functionality:

[image: title]

And the TOC entries have the long form too:

[image: contents]

And for the sake of completeness, here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\headnameref

% headers
\copypagestyle{maudcyclo}{plain}
\createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{\sectionname}{}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{maudcyclo}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\scshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{maudcyclo}{}{\scshape\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}

\makeevenhead{plain}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}

% don't number chapters and below
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\pagestyle{maudcyclo} % use header style

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\H@old@sectm@m}
  {\csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}}
  {\csname #1mark\endcsname{#9}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\H@old@sectm@m}
  {\fi #7}
  {\fi #9}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section[Section One][S1]{Section One (long title)}
\label{sec1}
Here is some text for section one.
\clearpage

\section[Section Two][S2]{Section Two (long title)}
Here I will reference \nameref{sec1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but it's not working for me. Is this dependent on using the memoir class? I'm not using that class, and it'll be great if your solution can work with any class.

Comment: @Felipe - Unfortunately `latexdef H@old@sectm@m` returns 'undefined'. Seems to me that it is a deprecated internal `hyperref` macro. I'll try to figure out how to implement the solution in the current version.

Comment: @Felipe - I have not tested it right now. What I think at the moment is that the `\NR@sect` macro of the nameref module from `hyperref` fulfills the same purpose as `\H@old@sectm@m`. Try `\patchcmd{\NR@sect}...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different reference specifically for `\nameref`, then define a new name using the following macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\namerefname}[1]{\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}}% New \nameref name
\makeatother
```

Here's your example showing its usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\headnameref

% headers
\copypagestyle{maudcyclo}{plain}
\createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{\sectionname}{}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{maudcyclo}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\scshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{maudcyclo}{}{\scshape\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{maudcyclo}{}{}{}

\makeevenhead{plain}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}{\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}

% don't number chapters and below
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\pagestyle{maudcyclo} % use header style

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\namerefname}[1]{\edef\@currentlabelname{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[Section ONE]{Section One}
\namerefname{S1}\label{sec1}
Here is some text for \nameref{sec1}.

\section[Section TWO]{Section Two}
\label{sec2}
Here is some text for \nameref{sec2}.

\end{document}
```